# Get One Top Image for each category

Tags: t-sql

I have grouped photos into categories . ( 2 tables categories and photos with catID field)

I have  a query that returns a list of categories and the number of photos it has and imagename of its top photo ( each photo record has a field IsTop ) .

But it's not working properly . it just returns imagepath for first record . for rest it returns null

```
select
T3.ImagePath,T2.ID,T2.Title,T2.ItemsCount 
from (
select C.Title,C.ID,Count(Ph.CatID) as ItemsCount from Categories C
    left Outer join (select CatID from photos) Ph
    on C.ID=Ph.CatID group by C.Title,C.ID) T2 
left outer join 
(select top 1 ImagePath,CatID from photos where IsTop=1 order by id desc) T3 
on T2.ID=T3.CatID 
group by T3.ImagePath,T2.ID,T2.Title,T2.ItemsCount;
```

Comment: What does `IsTop` mean? If there's only one set for each `CatID`, why are you doing a `top 1` at all? If there are *multiple* rows in `photos` for which `IsTop=1`, for the same `CatID`, which one is meant to be selected (and don't say "the first", or something like that - we need a definition based on the values of other columns)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : IsTop is used to show an image for each category in webpage . yes it's possible to have multiple records with IsTop true for each CatID . and I want to select the last one ( newest one ) for each record .and finally I mean with this query if it returns 4 categories then just the first record in results set contains imagepath and 3 others have null ) thanx

Comment: which part of "don't say "the first"" meant you though specifying "the last" would be right? We need a *definition* of which "the last" is, based on an *explicit* ordering that you need to provide us with information on - which columns in `photo` define the order by which we can determine "the last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use a [windowing function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
select
T3.ImagePath,T2.ID,T2.Title,T2.ItemsCount 
from (
select C.Title,C.ID,Count(Ph.CatID) as ItemsCount from Categories C
    left Outer join (select CatID from photos) Ph
    on C.ID=Ph.CatID group by C.Title,C.ID) T2 
left outer join 
(select ImagePath,CatID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatID ORDER BY ID desc) as rn from photos where IsTop=1) T3 
on T2.ID=T3.CatID and rn = 1 /* <-- New join condition also */
group by T3.ImagePath,T2.ID,T2.Title,T2.ItemsCount;
```

In this case, it allows us to number the rows, with row numbers being assigned independently for each `CatID` (the `PARTITION BY` bit), and with a specific ordering. For each `CatID`, we start assigning row numbers again starting at 1.